# Poisson Distribution: P(exceeds certain number)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

A professor plans to schedule an open lab in order to provide answers and additional
help to students in the hour before homework is due. The number of students who will
come to open lab will vary from week to week, and the professor assumes the count in
a particular week will follow a Poisson(15) distribution.

The professor is offered a room for the open lab, but is concerned that the room
capacity of 23 won’t be sufficient. Compute the probability that the number of
students who come to open lab in a particular week will exceed the room capacity.

---

I get that λ=15, but how do you find P(X > 23)? Would it be 1-P(0 < X ≤ 23)? That would take ages to calculate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you have learned in class so far, your professor may want you to consider

1) Writing a program to sum up $p=\sum_{k=0}^{23} P(X=k)$ and then to compute $1-p$.

2) Noting that for $\lambda$ large, $\mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda) \approx N(\lambda,\lambda)$, i.e. you can use a normal approximation to your Poisson.

Comment: They recommend we use the program "R" in the class. If I wrote a program for your notation in 1), that would give me the probability of the number of students NOT exceeding the room capacity, correct? So would I then do 1-(result)?

Comment: @wad11656: you can directly use $1-ppois(23,15)$ in R.

Comment: Thank you, gents. I haven't been using R the whole semester, but this is a situation where I really needed a program to do the calculations. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Since $\lambda>10$, you can approximate using Normal distribution, $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ with $\mu=\lambda$ and $\sigma^2=\lambda$

Using this information, we need to find $\Pr(X>23)=1-\Pr(X\le 23).$ We can convert this to standard normal and then look it up on the standard normal distribution table. We have
$$Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}=\frac{23-15}{\sqrt{15}}=\frac{8}{\sqrt{15}}=2.07$$
Now, you need to find $1-\Pr(Z<2.07)$

Comment: This has already been pointed out in the answer below. Unless you add more context, I shall regretfully downvote this answer.

Comment: @voldemort Added more context.

Comment: Downvote retracted with pleasure.